# Can I ask a question here for verification only, but not to get an answer?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to post my question here for **verification** only but not to get an answer?

I just want to make sure that my question is on-topic and fits the rules in the help center, like it's not too broad, etc.

This is analogous to the idea when you have created an application and you want first to test it in QA and release beta version of that application first before releasing the released version of the application to the customer, because you never can know if you have bugs in the application you are developing or not.

So I never know if my question will get downvoted or not, so I am not taking risks anymore. I want that every question that I ask in this network outside meta won't get downvoted ever.

The main reason that I want to do this is because that many downvoted questions block me from asking questions forever and asking questions in the Stack Exchange community is very important for me and I don't want to get to the state that I can't ask questions anymore ever. Also downvotes decrease my reputation and I also don't want to lose reputations, but I want to gain reputation by upvotes instead, because I need this reputation for several purposes, like creating chat rooms (at least 20 reputations required) adding comments (at least 50 reputations required), downvoting (at least 125 reputations required), creating tags (at least 300 reputations required), starting bounties, which are very important to receive more attention, attract more answerers and increase views.

So from now on I want to post my question here for validation purposes only and if it passes then I will post it outside meta for answers.

Comment: I asked similar question in physics meta stack exchange and it got upvotes instead of downvotes. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/is-this-legal-to-post-my-physics-question-here-for-verification-only-but-not-for Why this question gets downvotes?

Comment: Based on your questions here, my guess is that the main reason you get downvotes is due to lack of searching for an answer before asking. You also seem to largely refuse constructive input, whether that's in terms of continuing to use bold the way you do despite that being edited out of every other post of yours or having others point out that your question is a duplicate or your lack of research effort, but you continue to not do any research in subsequent questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is it legal? I don't know. I suppose Stack Overflow the company won't sue you if you post something like that here.

It is off-topic here? Yes. If you want to know upfront if a question of yours would be well received on a certain site, you need to ask it on that site's *own Meta*, or else in a chatroom on that site. Meta Stack Exchange is full of people who generally know how the network works, but we're not experts on each site's individual policies/voting habits, like which questions are well-received and which not. We can only give *general* advice (including [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) – note that most answers on those questions end with 'please check their help center before posting a question').

Also, be prepared that if you're going to, e.g., Physics Meta for *every* question you want to ask on the (main) Physics site, you'll be bound to eventually get downvotes as well. You're expected to do research before posting a question, which also means researching about what a good question is and what not (i.e., by looking in the help center, and analyzing similar questions).

Answer (score 7):

It does not seem fair to ask volunteers to spend their time to check and improve your questions for the sole purpose of maximising the chance that they will be well received.

It is I think impossible that anyone apart from an SE developer would be able to guarantee you immunity from downvotes, and I would not expect them to spend developer resources doing that.

Answer (score 6):

First of all a big lol

> I need these reputations for several purposes ... downvoting (at least 125 reputations required)

You're so selfish. No one should downvote you but you want to downvote others.

#### Now let's check the points in your question

> Is this legal to post my question here for verification only but not for answer?

There is no legal issue. But that is not the purpose of Stack Exchange sites. If you want an answer, post it. If you have an answer, post it in QA style.

If you want a question stay unanswered, don't post it.

> I just want to make sure that my question is on-topic, not off-topic, and fits the rules in the help center, like it's not too broad and etc.

If you have access to chat, you can ask there. You can also read the site's on-topic section to understand it yourself.

> So I never know if my question will get downvoted or no, so I am not taking risks anymore. I want that every question that I ask in this network outside meta won't get downvoted ever

Downvotes are upto people.

If Jon Skeet upvoted a question, it doesn't mean other shouldn't downvote it.

> The main reason that I want to do this is because that many downvoted questions block me for asking questions forever

If you delete the question upon downvote, it will also help you to get a question ban